# Ruby argument count error when passing in a &block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working on a text game engine, and have run into a snag while developing the exploration module. When I try and instantiate my `Location` class with a block argument from a fixture, I'm getting this error:

> ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

for this code:

```
# in lib/explore/models/location.rb, line 15
class Location < RoundTable::Controllers::ActionDelegate
  # ... code omitted for brevity

  def initialize(slug, params = nil, &block)
    # ... code omitted for brevity

    if block_given?
      parser = Explore::Parsers::LocationParser.new(self)
      parser.instance_eval &block
    end # if
  end # constructor

  # ... code omitted for brevity
end # class Location

# in spec/fixtures/models/locations.rb, line 38
location :mushroom_kingdom, :name => "Mushroom Kingdom" do
  edges = Explore::Fixtures[:edges]
  edges.each do |key, value|
    go value.location, *value.params
  end # each
end # location

# in spec/models/location_spec.rb, line 193
context "initialized with block" do
  let :fixture do fixtures[:mushroom_kingdom] end

  subject { described_class.new fixture.slug, fixture.params, &fixture.block }

  it { puts subject.inspect }
end # context initialized with block
```

It's pretty obviously a syntax error somewhere, where a block isn't getting converted to a proc or vice versa, but I've been over the code a dozen times and can't find it. If any eagle-eyed readers can help me out, I would be eternally grateful.

**Source Files:**

- [location.rb (Github)](https://github.com/sleepingkingstudios/round_table--text_explorer/blob/master/lib/explore/models/location.rb)
- [location_spec.rb (Github)](https://github.com/sleepingkingstudios/round_table--text_explorer/blob/master/spec/models/location_spec.rb)
- [(fixtures) locations.rb (Github)](https://github.com/sleepingkingstudios/round_table--text_explorer/blob/master/spec/fixtures/models/locations.rb)

The full source is available on Github, but is split between two repositories:

- [the engine (Github)](https://github.com/sleepingkingstudios/round-table)
- [the plugin (Github)](https://github.com/sleepingkingstudios/round_table--text_explorer)

To run code or specs, the plugin code needs to be placed inside the engine directory in vendor/modules/plugins/explore.

**Backtrace:**

```
1) RoundTable::Vendor::Plugins::Explore::Models::Location initialization with block 
     Failure/Error: it { expect { described_class.new fixture.slug, fixture.params, &fixture.block }.not_to raise_error ArgumentError }
       expected no ArgumentError, got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)>
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) RoundTable::Vendor::Plugins::Explore::Models::Location initialized with block 
     Failure/Error: subject { described_class.new fixture.slug, fixture.params, &fixture.block }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
     # ./lib/explore/parsers/location_parser.rb:39:in `go'
     # ./spec/fixtures/models/locations.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Models>'
     # ./spec/fixtures/models/locations.rb:40:in `each'
     # ./spec/fixtures/models/locations.rb:40:in `block in <module:Models>'
     # ./lib/explore/models/location.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
     # ./lib/explore/models/location.rb:49:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:196:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:196:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:198:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Edit 2012年06月06日:**

- Replaced sample code with actual, non-conforming code
- Added links to full project

Comment: Where's the actual error? What do you do with the block? It's not in the `Location` constructor.

Comment: **Edit 2012年06月06日:** Replaced sample code with actual, non-conforming code; Added links to full project. Sorry, was trying to rush off the question during a lunch break when I had wifi. Hopefully this will be more illuminating.

Comment: @DaveNewton The block gets passed to a parser that handles the creation DSL. I set it up that way to avoid naming conflicts between DSL elements and actual instance methods. Hopefully it is more clear after the edit.

Comment: @Merlin Thanks for wasting our time!!

Comment: @Anil Again, my apologies, and thank you for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rspec sometimes swallows backtraces in ways that aren't completely helpful (i think you can use the -b option to suppress this ) - the error is (I think) elsewhere.

From my reading of the code, mushroom kingdom's block is instance_evaled on an instance of `Explore::Parsers::LocationParser`

This class defines a `go` method like so

```
def go(location, params = {})
```

but mushroom kingdom does

```
go value.location, *value.params
```

where `value.params` is the hash of options used to create an edge at the bottom of your edges fixtures file. In at least one case, that hash has 2 objects in it, so when you splat that you end up calling `go` with 3 arguments. Given that `go` appears to take a hash as its second argument, was that splat really intentional?

Comment: You, good sir, have hit it on the head. x_x I spent two days looking for a misplaced ampersand or something. All the specs run correctly now. Thank you *so* much. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Location.new(fixture[:slug], fixture[:params], fixture[:block])
```

Comment: Why would that work? Location's initialize method takes two arguments, you're calling it with three.

Comment: The third argument is the block, isn't it?

Comment: The only ways to pass a block to a method are a) to pass a block to the method (i.e. `foo(bar, baz) do end`) or b) converting a Proc object (or convertible) to a block using the `&` operator (i.e. `foo(bar, baz, &bay)`. Doing `foo(bar, baz, bay)` without the `&` when `foo` is a method that takes two arguments and a block will cause an argument error because you supplied three arguments to a method that takes two.

Comment: Just tried it out and you are right. But it behaves strange in my opinion. Why would you need to convert to block something that is a block already? I thought it would work more like passing by reference in C++. Although you can always leave out the '&' from the method definition. Then you can supply Procs and lambdas as normal arguments.

Comment: "Why would you need to convert to block something that is a block already?" Because it's not a block already. Blocks aren't objects. Was that the best design decision? I don't know, but it's the way it is. "Although you can always leave out the '&' from the method definition. Then you can supply Procs and lambdas as normal arguments." Yes, but then you can't pass regular blocks to the method anymore.

Comment: I see. Well definitely better to know than complain. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a replica of what you have and it works. Still looking for the problem.

```
class Location
   def initialize(slug, params = nil, &block)
     yield
   end
end


mushroom_kingdom = 'mushroom kingdom'
fixture = {
  :slug => mushroom_kingdom,
  :params => { :princess => :toadstool },
  :block => lambda { puts "It'sa me, Mario!" }
}
l = Location.new(fixture[:slug], fixture[:params],&fixture[:block])
```

To get the same error, I have to do `Location.new(fixture[:slug], fixture[:params], 'abcd', &fixture[:block])` or `Location.new(fixture[:slug], fixture[:params],fixture[:block])`. It is almost as if your `&` is not really an ampersand. Is it some other character-encoding? Do any of the first two parameters have a comma?

And, are you sure the error is coming from exactly this code? There is no syntax error in what you have shared.

Comment: Sure, he does. If he wants to call new with two arguments and one block, he needs the `&`. What you're doing is calling it with 3 arguments, but Location's initialize method doesn't take 3 arguments. So that's wrong.

Comment: @sepp2k I saw `def initialize(slug, params = nil, &block)` for `Location`.

Comment: Yapp. That's two arguments (one of them optional) and one block.

Comment: See [this pastie](http://codepad.org/tTDGov9l) as a demonstration of how your proposed fix actually causes the error message the OP is complaining about rather than fixing it.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry everyone, this is what happens when I try and rush off a question during a lunch break. I've replaced the code in the question with (hopefully) the relevant code from the project, and added links/instructions for the whole project as well in case that helps.